# Error 400 on LAN access

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, local-area-network, 400

Probably a stupid question / problem, but when I try and access my site via it's domain name from inside it's LAN (requesting via the local IP address works fine though), I get an error 400.

A while back, when requesting my site from it's LAN via the domain address, I would be redirected to my router's configuration page (as you'd expect from an internal request) but that is no longer the case. I don't remember changing anything that could lead to such symptoms so I'm asking for peace of mind in case I'm doing something wrong.

I'm running Apache2 with 3 virtual hosts resolving via http headers.

Apache2 logs are clean from these requests...

Everything works as expected

- for an external request
- for an internal client using a web proxy

Is "error 400: Bad Request" Apache's normal response for an internal request via it's domain name?
... if that makes any sense.

Any confirmation is appreciated!

Comment: Are you even sure the response is coming from Apache and not your gateway?

Comment: That's a good point. No, I'm not sure. How would I go about determining that? Wireshark?

Comment: Before you go to wireshark, look in your Apache logs, /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error.log.  That should always be the first place you look to find out what's going on with Apache.

Comment: Rebooted the router (and redid the port-forwarding). Still nothing. Error logs only have notices regarding PERL and some other things: `[Thu Dec 26 12:10:49 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Thu Dec 26 12:10:49 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Thu Dec 26 12:10:49 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.3.17 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.3 mod_perl/2.0.6 Perl/v5.16.2 configured -- resuming normal operations` these appear only when starting Apache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You need to edit your httpd.conf by adding this line :

> HttpProtocolOptions unsafe